# Understanding 16 MB limit and data modelling

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB 16MB limit apply to a single denormalized db document, or to each embedded document in particular? In one-to-many relationships with embedded documents, do all the "many" documents have to be less than 16 MB in size altogether?

I'm asking this because I can't choose my data model yet - Its recommended for "contains" relationships (which is exactly my case) to stick to the denormalized strategy, but I believe the sub-documents will exceed 16 MB in sum. Will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One whole doc, regardless of the complexity of the shape and level of embedding, if any, cannot exceed 16MB.